# d3.json does not load file from App_Data folder of ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, d3.js, geojson

I need to load a Geojson file from "App_Data" folder of ASP.NET MVC and use it in d3.json.

```
d3.json("@Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/data/afile.geojson")", function (error, geodata) {
    if (error) return console.log(error);

    features.selectAll("path")
        .data(geodata.features)
        ...
}
```

I see the error:

```
error { target: XMLHttpRequest, isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, currentTarget: XMLHttpRequest, eventPhase: 2, bubbles: false, cancelable: false, defaultPrevented: false, … }
```

In "View Page Source":

```
d3.json("C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ASP.NET\app\app\App_Data\data\afile.geojson", function (error, geodata) {
    if (error) return console.log(error);
    ...
}
```

How to slove this?

Answer (score 0):

The code below should be added to Web.config (not web.config).

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".geojson" mimeType="application/geojson" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Use file(s) in a folder named for example "Data".

```
d3.json("/Data/geo/afile.geojson", function (error, geodata) {
```

... }

I see the error when using "App_Data" folder.

```
d3.json("/App_Data/geo/afile.geojson", function (error, geodata) {
```

... }